# Can’t restore Time Machine back up - an error occurred while adding recovery system to destination disk

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, backup, time-machine, disk-utility

Just upgraded my 2012(mid) non-retina  13” MacBook Pro with a crucial
sad 1tb and having troubles restoring back up from Time machine. I’m
sure it’s important to mention I installed a new data cable as well.

The steps I used were: In the recovery mode, I erase the hard drive
in the disk utilities section and then go to back up from time
machine. I go through all the steps to select the time machine and
back up version. It seems to start the back up for a few moments but
then I get an error:

“An error occurred while adding a recovery system to the destination
disk. Restart your computer, and then try restoring again.”

I’ve gone throug a couple of cycles of this, consulting you tube each
time to see if I’m missing something or if trying a couple of
different steps in the disk utility menu helps.  My backup is
encrypted and I did not select the Mac Extended + Journaled
(encrypted) format just the Mac Extended + Journaled format.

I’m lost and don’t know what to do and what to try to resolve this.

Comment: How exactly did you erase the drive?

Comment: Internet recovery, disk utility, erase with extended journal

Answer (score 0):

Try this·

Go to the Internet Recovery, erase the drive in Journaled format, and then restore.

I suspect, in your case, erasing the drive from Recovery is not the correct approach.

Comment: If OP installed a new drive into his system there's no Recovery partition to even boot from, so he's likely already using internet recovery.

Comment: Already using internet recovery

Answer (score 0):

Update: not sure what I did but after 4th failed attempt I turned on computer and left it overnight, went to utilities this morning and it was a different panel, this one looked more modern and allowed me to partition the disk in APFS and this seemed to work, disk is now restoring. Not sure at all what happened here but it is good now.